# How can I determine on my system where process substitution creates FIFO files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fifo

I'm writing a C++ application and need to work with process substitution in the Bash shell.

I'm trying to find a way to validate the paths passed as arguments to my program, some of which point to FIFO files created by process substitution.

Is there a shell (or C++) way that I can check if the system creates these files in `/dev/fd` or if they are created somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do this.  Just because a directory is where bash defaults to putting fifo paths, doesn't mean that a particular fifo in that directory was created by bash, or that it was passed by bash as an argument to your command.

Take a look at the bigger picture of your problem.  What are you REALLY trying to solve?

If you're trying to solve, "the output of my program must always be piped into another program," then don't require the user to use bash's obscure process substitution.  What if the default shell on their system is zsh?  Bourne shell?  Korn shell?

Instead, have your program create a pipe, fork, and exec the other program.

So, what are you really trying to do?  What happens if you, God forbid, write your output to a file the user of your program passed, instead of to a fifo created by bash?

Comment: I agree, this requirement is a bit obscure! However unfortunately I can't change it as the application is a software simulator that emulates the behaviour of another application that runs embedded on some hardware - the application it is emulating wasn't written by me and I can't change it's argument structure. Since the use cases for such a simulator are pretty limited, it's unlikely it will present a problem, I just wondered if there was an easy way to check (bash config file or something). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-p` option to `test` if a file is a pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
if [ -p "$file" ]
then
    echo "$file is a pipe"
fi
```

Demo:

```
$ myscript.sh <(echo hello)
/dev/fd/63 is a pipe
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be useful to construct a solution, however it doesn't tell me where these files are created by default (/dev/fd on most systems). Is there an environment variable or something that I could check to see what path this is?

Comment: why? You shouldn't need to know where they are created.

Comment: The reason I need to know is to validate paths passed as an argument to my application.

Essentially what I call is `myProg -fifopaths >(/run/some/application)` what my program sees passed as the arguments to its main is `/path/to/myProg -fifopaths /dev/fd/63` etc.

I need to validate that any paths passed to my program are in fact in `/dev/fd` to be sure they are paths to a FIFO. The problem arises that if my program is executed on _System-X_ where FIFO paths are not in `/dev/fd`, I need to know where these FIFO paths are supposed to be on _System-X_ in order to validate the arguments.